# Is Boston Dynamics developing the quadruped robot in this video?

Tags: robotics

This [June 2018 episode](https://youtu.be/lXTkXYjO6u0?t=13m43s) of [Frankie Boyle's New World Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankie_Boyle%27s_New_World_Order) shows a video snippet purportedly of a quadruped Boston Dynamics robot capable of opening a door.

Is such a robot actually in development?

Comment: The linked video is pretty strong evidence in my opinion. What further proof are you looking for?

Comment: @Laurel: I *suspect* the OP thinks the video has been faked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Boston Dynamics](https://www.bostondynamics.com/) is a real company, and they are really doing this stuff. In addition to all the [videos of their various robots](https://www.youtube.com/user/BostonDynamics) on YouTube, here is [one example paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sfeng/sf_hum14.pdf) jointly authored with a scientist at CMU explaining how the motion control dynamics work.